# matplotlib | TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'float'

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I draw a *FancyBboxPatch* on a plot with a date x-axis. The *FancyBboxPatch* should stretch over a specific time period, similar to a gantt chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = [('2019-04-15', 'Start'), ('2019-05-01', 'Stop')]
date, labels = zip(*data)
frame = pd.DataFrame({'bla': labels}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(date))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12.5, 2.5))

for index, row in frame.iterrows():

    ax.text(index, 0.5, row['bla'])

ax.set_xlim([frame.index[0], frame.index[-1]])

plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried to copy and paste and adjust code from the [Matplotlib website](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-artist-reference-py). However, this caused errors which were related to the date axis and the width of the patch.

**Update**

I tried with the code below. However, it returns `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'float'`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

data = [('2019-04-15', 'Start'), ('2019-05-01', 'Stop')]
date, labels = zip(*data)
frame = pd.DataFrame({'bla': labels}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(date))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12.5, 2.5))

for index, row in frame.iterrows():

    ax.text(index, 0.5, row['bla'])

ax.set_xlim([frame.index[0], frame.index[-1]])

ax.add_patch(
    mpatches.FancyBboxPatch(
        (frame.index[0],0.5),  # xy
        100,  # width
        0.5,  # heigth
        boxstyle=mpatches.BoxStyle("Round", pad=0.02)
        )
    )

plt.show()
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Sorry, I will elaborate.

Comment: I suppose there's something wrong with my x,y coordinates? I cannot combine float and a timestamp. However, y is not a time-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `matplotlib.dates.date2num(d)` from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num) to convert your datetime objects to Matplotlib dates like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.dates as dates

data = [('2019-04-15', 'Start'), ('2019-05-01', 'Stop')]
date, labels = zip(*data)
frame = pd.DataFrame({'bla': labels}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(date))

print(f'frame.index[0] {frame.index[0]}')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12.5, 2.5))

for index, row in frame.iterrows():

    ax.text(index, 0.5, row['bla'])

ax.set_xlim([frame.index[0], frame.index[-1]])

ax.add_patch(
    mpatches.FancyBboxPatch(
        (dates.date2num(frame.index[0]),0.5),  # Conversion
        100,  # width
        0.5,  # heigth
        boxstyle=mpatches.BoxStyle("Round", pad=0.02)
        )
    )

plt.show()
```